# Flutter iterating thorug array of objects and displaying name of each object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of members `List<AllMembers> _clanoviZaDijeljenje = [];` and I want to iterate thorugh this list and display name of each member. I'm tryng something like this
`_clanoviZaDijeljenje.map((member) { return Text(member.name);});` and i get error: The element type 'Iterable' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

Comment: try this : _clanoviZaDijeljenje.map((e)=> Text(e.name)).toList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `.map` returns `Iterable<T>`.
Whenever you need a list you have to cast iterable to the list by adding `.toList()`:

```
_clanoviZaDijeljenje.map((member) { return Text(member.name);}).toList();
```

Comment: So  should add members to the list with map, and then to display names iterate thorugh that list?

Comment: ```var members = _clanoviZaDijeljenje.map((member) { return Text(member.name);}).toList();``` then display the list:
```Column(children: members)```
You can omit assigning members variable and directly assign children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach cycle.

First way:

```
_clanoviZaDijeljenje.forEach((member) return Text(member.name));
```

Second way:

```
for(Member member in _clanoviZaDijeljenje){ return Text(member.name);}
```